# How to use if-else in Stream.of() in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, java-stream, java-11

I have a piece of code using which I am combining two strings.

```
String result = Stream.of(student.getFirstName(), student.getLastName())
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(". "));
```

Few of the first names contains "." at the end of the string. So I want to place an if condition to check if the string contains "." at the end then skip `Collectors.join(".")`
Edit- `student.getLastName()` will return a string which has "." at the end. I also want to keep it as is.

Comment: IMHO you should clean your input before working on the data. I would replace all dots from the first name before this stream operation.

Comment: This can be done on the fly in the stream too. And he mentioned only the dot at the end not all dots (maybe in the middle).

Answer (score 1):

There is no if/else in Java streams. Use `Stream.map` to remove the dot *if* the name contains a dot as first letter and then just join using `Collectors.join(".")`

```
String result = Stream.of(student.getFirstName(), student.getLastName())
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(name -> name.endsWith(".") ? name.substring(0, name.length() - 1) : name)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(". "));
```

Comment: `name.charAt(0) == '.'` would only check for the first character in the string. The op mentioned that the `.`s are at the end.

Comment: Ooops my bad.. somehow read at the beginning, will fix it :D

Comment: @Holger this works correct but it also removes "." at the end of the second string i.e. `student.getLastName()`. Is there any way we can preserve "." at the end of lastName.

Comment: @AnamQureshi what if there is no dot after the last name? Do you want to add a dot or not?

Comment: @Holger I want to keep the lastName as it is. If lastName contains dot at the end then it should be there, if not, then it should not be there.

Comment: @AnamQureshi the Stream API is designed for processing a potentially large number of objects in a uniform way. Processing two elements in a different way is as far from this intended use case as one can get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replace()`:

```java
String firstName = student.getFirstName().replace('.', '');
```

Though I'm not sure why you need to use a `Stream` in your scenario, you could simply just do:

```java
String result = student.getFirstName().replace('.', '') + "." + student.getLastName();
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Your alternative solution to streams doesn't check for nulls. It seems like both first name and last name could be null.

Comment: @Sweeper I left it out on purpose as the OP didn't post the context of the function, if it were inside a loop does it need to bail out, of if it's within a method itself does it need to just `return`? If the question gets updated then I can update the answer to reflect it.

Comment: You can not define a “character that is not a character” like `''` or, in other words, you can not use `replace(char,char)` to remove characters.